# Managing pictures and videos between my iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, photos.app, photos

I take a lot of photos and videos with my iPhone, and like to have *most* of them on my iPad. However, often, I take and combine videos with iMovie eliminating the need to have 10-20+ videos of whatever that was in my Photos app. Right now I sync through iTunes into iPhoto, but that has become an immense space hog for two reasons. One is the videos, (I have the one completed video, and don't need all the clips) and two, iPhoto likes to create Photostream events that downloads all my Photostream pictures into separate Events(resulting in loads of duplicates as well). To finish the loop, I have my iPad sync the last three months of events.

**Is there a better way to manage pictures *and* videos?**

I would like to use something like a (iPhoto) Smart Album that only *imports* media, and then lets me delete whatever out that I want to.

Answer (score 2):

Apple wants you to use their PhotoStream or do manual syncing all the time. From my personal experience it's impossible to manage some parts in PhotoStream and some others outside. I'm sure it's possible to do some crazy scripting, symlinking and syncing. But hey... that's not the reason why we use Apple products in favor to the more open Android ones, right?

I ended up re-creating my Aperture and iPhoto libraries and a big upload session to PhotoStream. Works fine so far.

Comment: I do use Photostream and really like it, but it doesn't handle my videos, and it only stores the last 30 days of pictures, roughly.

Answer (score 0):

what i would do, turn of automatic download in iphoto on your mac, therfore you know what u want from you photostream and what not! second, deactivate photostream on you iPad, but share a photostream from you iPhone to your iPad, rather from your self to yourself. when ever you wanna move to your iPad, just share the pics pic up your iPad, go nuts, and when you are by your comp, just select the ones you want....

was i clear enough?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: I really like Photostream - it works really well for pictures - I would be sad to turn it off. Shared Photostreams are nice too. I'm afraid I didn't understand how that would help manage videos? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: okey, you might want to take a look at google+, if i understood you correctly now, my dyslexia is acting up :P or with other photoupload services like dropbox?



but you are absolutly right, photostream deff needs video support!, thing is its a huge data-hog! even on some broad bands