# Get video from iPhone Videos app onto Mac/PC

Tags: iphone, itunes, video, file-transfer

So a friend of mine has a video in the "Videos" app under "Home Videos" that was created using iMovie on his Mac.

His mac has since been wiped and he's lost the video. It is however still on his iPhone. Is there any way to extract the video from there? I can't see an open in option or anything. The device can't be jail broken due to some MDM software on it.

Thanks all!

Comment: Hi welcome to AskDifferent, [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/76180/10733) answer may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming iOS 7.

If the iPhone has been synced with the target Mac, it should be straightforward. Go to the home folder and then go into the folders in succession

Music -> iTunes -> iTunes Music -> Movies

Once in the Movies folder, all the movies that you see on your iPhone should be visible. Then copy that file to wherever else you want it.