# Add video to camera roll without using iPhoto?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, photos.app

I have a bunch of video recorded and stored in Dropbox from another iOS device, I'd like to move this onto a new iOS device.

So far, the only way I can see of adding these videos to my Camera Roll is to put them into iPhoto on the Mac, add them to an album, then Sync that Album to the new device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I found in the end was to use iTunes, select Photo syncing then instead of using iPhoto, manually selecting a folder full of video. This had to be video that iOS could play natively, it didn't do any kind of conversion or compression.

Comment: This worked for me using with a .mp4 file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn't currently have a good system for manually putting media *onto* your iOS device. [I asked a similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53916/managing-pictures-between-my-iphone-and-ipad), and came to the conclusion that transferring large numbers of videos to an iOS device is a job left largely to iPhoto. The process you described is the best that I have found.

Depending on the number of videos you have and how much time you want to put into you may have a couple options, aside from iPhoto.

1. You could try using [SimplTransfer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/simple-photo-video-transfer/id420821506?mt=8) to transfer between devices.

   - I've tried using it, but it seems to timeout or come up with some error when I'm transferring videos. There is a [full version](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/simple-transfer/id411292121?mt=8), which may or may not be better.
2. It is possible to email videos (tap and hold video in Mail.app to save) to yourself, and then save them to the device.

   - I'm guessing iOS compresses the video before sending it, so you likely will end up with a loss of quality in the end device.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a simple solution, first select your videos and then transfer them via Airdrop, piece of cake.. Just turn it on, on both devices, select them and send ^^

Answer (score 0):

if its your new primary device you could use icloud, however, manually its ether with an app like [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) or get the Dropbox app and saving them!

Answer (score 0):

First download the app "Download Manager Lite" then email the viedeo to yourslef. Then go on download manager, and open your email, and press save to camera roll. Hope this hwlps!!

Comment: Instead of having everybody search for the app themselves, can you please add a link to the app and also write a few words on why you recommend it?

Comment: Emailing a bunch of videos to myself is not really an option.